# Does a frosted glass cause any significant dilution of the beer it holds?

Tags: serving, temperature

I've always been a fan of "the colder the better".  I enjoy using a glass that has been placed in the freezer.

Obviously, in this scenario, there's frozen condensation on it, but is this enough to dilute the beer such that I'm destroying the flavor by doing so?

Comment: It's worth noting that the frosted appearance is not a requirement for an ice cold glass but is achieved by first rinsing the glass to coat it in water.  If you only rinse the outside, there shouldn't be extra ice on the inside.

Comment: The biggest issue I've encountered with frosted glasses is ice in my beer. This shouldn't happen, but at some bars, it does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say that the condensate amounts to no more than 1ml for a 500ml glass, which is a 0.2% dilution.

No to be too coarse, but I imagine most people dilute the beer more after taking a sip!

Comparatively, I think the excessively cold temperature will contribute more to destroying the flavor than a small amount of condensate from the glass.

So, if you enjoy the beer in a frozen glass, then keep at it.

Comment: +1 for excessively cold serving temperatures destroying the flavor.

Comment: On that point, related: [How does serving temperature affect the taste of beers?](http://beer.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-does-serving-temperature-affect-the-taste-of-beers)

Answer (score 3):

In France we're told that you should always rince the glass with a bit of cold water before serving to remove any trace of dust which will make the foam smoother.
Since you're not supposed to dry it afterward, I guess that would dilute the beer more than the fozen condensation and it's still not enough water to have any impact on the flavor.

Comment: Great advice! I always rinse my glasses first and give them a shake. What's left is really minuscule.